# Compression of PDF with added images on preview

Tags: pdf, preview

I have a PDF to which I copied and pasted an image. I am trying to compress the PDF with preview, but whenever I try it, the compression happens only to the original contents of the pdf and not to the added image. Has anyone faced a similar issue?

- How can I compress the PDF with all its contents?
- Alternatively, since the pdf contains only images and no text, how can I convert (or save) the pdf so that I cannot resize the added image anymore?

Comment: When you say "compressed", do you mean reduced in physical dimensions, or reduced in file size, e.g. ZIP compression? Can you explain your process of compressing the PDF a bit more? What version of macOS?

Comment: @benwiggy Thank you for your comment. Apologies for the potential confusion. I meant attempting to reduce the file size. For example, in preview, I use the Quarz filter.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in Quartz Filters that reduce file size are not that good, and many people have made better Quartz Filters that improve the way compression is handled.

https://github.com/joshcarr/Apple-Quartz-Filters

It's also important to remember that if an image is already compressed, e.g. JPEG, then further compression to the PDF container will not reduce the file size significantly, if at all.